# Conditions for positivity of this symmetric real matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I have the following real symmetric matrix $M$ of size 3:

\begin{align}
M = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b & c \\
b & d & e \\
c & e & f
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}

for real parameters $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on these parameters for $M$ to be a positive matrix ($M \geq 0$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to matrix to be positive-semidefinite, the condition is: the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are alternating. This is equivalent to: for every $k$, the sum of principal $k\times k$ minors is $\ge 0$. In this case, $k$ runs from $1$ to $3$ and we get
$$a + d + f \ge 0\\
 a d  + a f + d f- b^2 - c^2 - e^2 \ge 0\\
 a d f + 2 b c e - a e^2 - b^2 f - c^2 d \ge 0$$

An equivalent set of conditions is: every principal minor is $\ge 0$ (apparently stronger than the above, but in fact equivalent).

Note: Leading minors $\ge 0$ may not be enough, as a diagonal matrix starting with $0$ shows.

Comment: Where does the second constraint come from?

Comment: @Sid: 2nd line, LHS $=$ sum of principal $2\times 2$ minors

Comment: @Sid: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Other_applications) for the def of principal minors, leading minors

Answer (score 0):

$D_k : k$-th order principal minor of $A$

$A_{n×n}$ is positive matrix if $D_k\ge 0\space \forall k=1, 2,...,n$

$D_1 : det[a]_{1×1}= a\ge 0$

$D_2 : det \begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
b & d \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}=ad-b^2\ge 0$

$\begin{align} D_3&=  det
\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b & c \\
b & d & e \\
c & e & f\\
\end{pmatrix} \\ &= a d f-a e^2+b^2 (-f)+2 b c e-c^2 d \ge 0\end{align}$

Comment: The third one is from the determinant of all principal minors?

Comment: @Sid yes. $D_k $ principal  minor of order $k$.